# Определение падежа в предложении с помощью python

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

Здравствуйте дорогие программисты, я знаю звучит странно, но мне нужно определить падеж в предложении (русского языка).

Например:
У него проблемы - Именительный.
Актуальность проблемы - Родительный.
Он не рад проблеме - Дательный

Я пробовал сайт со склонением и описанием слов https://ru.wiktionary.org/

Update: denisnumb а можно каким либо образом сделать так, что существительное в предложении заменялось на его синоним сохраняя падеж. По моему примеру находим синоним и заменяем по вашему примеру.

Я написал лишь парсер который определяет синонимы слов и склоняет по падежам слово:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = "проблемы".lower()

word_s = requests.get("https://ru.wiktionary.org/w/index.php", {"search": s})


word = BeautifulSoup(word_s.text, 'lxml')
quote = word.find('span', class_="mw-headline", id="Синонимы")
print(quote.next.next.next.text)
print(quote.next.next.next.a.get("href"))
quote1 = word.find('table', class_="morfotable ru")
cases = quote1.tbody.find_all("tr")
case_l = []
for case in cases:
    _ = []
    for i in case.find_all("td"):
        a = i.text.replace("́", "").replace("\n", "")  # Здесь убирается ударение, символ ударения сюда не скопировался.
        _.append(a)
        if a == s:
            print(_[0], a)
    case_l.append(_)
print(case_l)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте `pymorphy2`:

```
pip install pymorphy2
```

**Документация [здесь](https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/index.html)**

---

Допустим, есть текст, в котором нужно определить падежи существительных:

```py
text = 'Актуальность проблем, связанных с изучением значения конфликтов в жизни общества и управлением конфликтами, является на сегодняшний день очевидной и относимой к числу приоритетных.'
```

Создадим список, который в виде словаря (`dict`) будет хранить отдельные слова предложения, а также информацию об их **падеже** и **части речи**

```py
import pymorphy2

morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()

text = 'Актуальность проблем, связанных с изучением значения конфликтов в жизни общества и управлением конфликтами, является на сегодняшний день очевидной и относимой к числу приоритетных.'

text_words = []
            # здесь мы создаем список отдельных слов предложения и убираем лишние символы (знаки препинания), оставляя только буквы
for word in [''.join([letter for letter in word if letter.isalpha()]) for word in text.split()]:
    word_info = morph.parse(word)[0]
    text_words.append(
        {
            'word': word,
            'case': word_info.tag.case,
            'POS': word_info.tag.POS
        })
```

Теперь выведем результат

```py
for word in text_words:
    print(word)
```

Вывод:

```py
{'word': 'Актуальность', 'case': 'accs', 'POS': 'NOUN'}
{'word': 'проблем', 'case': 'gent', 'POS': 'NOUN'}
{'word': 'связанных', 'case': 'gent', 'POS': 'ADJF'}
{'word': 'с', 'case': None, 'POS': 'PREP'}
{'word': 'изучением', 'case': 'ablt', 'POS': 'NOUN'}
{'word': 'значения', 'case': 'gent', 'POS': 'NOUN'}
{'word': 'конфликтов', 'case': 'gent', 'POS': 'NOUN'}
{'word': 'в', 'case': None, 'POS': 'PREP'}
{'word': 'жизни', 'case': 'gent', 'POS': 'NOUN'}
{'word': 'общества', 'case': 'gent', 'POS': 'NOUN'}
{'word': 'и', 'case': None, 'POS': 'CONJ'}
{'word': 'управлением', 'case': 'ablt', 'POS': 'NOUN'}
{'word': 'конфликтами', 'case': 'ablt', 'POS': 'NOUN'}
{'word': 'является', 'case': None, 'POS': 'VERB'}
{'word': 'на', 'case': None, 'POS': 'PREP'}
{'word': 'сегодняшний', 'case': 'accs', 'POS': 'ADJF'}
{'word': 'день', 'case': 'accs', 'POS': 'NOUN'}
{'word': 'очевидной', 'case': 'ablt', 'POS': 'ADJF'}
{'word': 'и', 'case': None, 'POS': 'CONJ'}
{'word': 'относимой', 'case': 'gent', 'POS': 'PRTF'}
{'word': 'к', 'case': None, 'POS': 'PREP'}
{'word': 'числу', 'case': 'datv', 'POS': 'NOUN'}
{'word': 'приоритетных', 'case': 'gent', 'POS': 'ADJF'}
```

Из таблицы, представленной в [**документации**](https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/grammemes.html#russian-pos) смотрим обозначения **падежей** *(case)* и **частей речи** *(POS - Part of speech)*. Например, `NOUN` - *существительное*, `gent` - *родительный падеж*

---

Далее, вашим методом получаем синонимы для нужных слов (часть речи и падеж каждого отдельного слова вы уже знаете) и заменяем в тексте указанное слово на новое через

```py
text = text.replace(old_word, new_word)
```

Если синоним стоит не в том падеже, в котором было исходное слово, через ту же библиотеку его можно поставить в нужный падеж:

```py
# ставим слово "изучение" в родительный падеж (gent)
morph.parse('изучение')[0].inflect({'gent'}).word
```

Вывод:

```
изучения
```

Comment: А можно каким либо образом сделать так, что существительное в предложении заменялось на его синоним сохраняя падеж. По моему примеру находим синоним и заменяем по вашему примеру.

Comment: Если можете то сделайте пожалуйста.

Comment: Если во всех случаях нужно заменить только последнее слово, то можно разбить предложение по пробелам (data = 'У него проблемы'.split()), а затем заменить последнее слово (`data[-1] = new_word`) и вернуть к строке (`' '.join(data)`)

Comment: Нет, мне нужно находить существительные и глаголы и заменять их на синонимы сохраняя падеж. Вот такие строки могут попадаться: Актуальность проблем, связанных с изучением значения конфликтов в жизни общества и управлением конфликтами, является на сегодняшний день
очевидной и относимой к числу приоритетных.

Comment: @ардуиноIDE постараюсь ответить, просто потому что самому стала интересна задача. Вообще, готовое решение здесь никто не пишет - за этим обычно надо обращаться к фрилансерам, разумеется, за деньги